# jquery manipulate ajax loading content

Tags: jquery

I pupulate with images a div by using ajax.

In the index page I have the  `$(document).ready(function () {` which manipulates the images loaded trough ajax. Should this work, because the ready function is alled before the images are loaded trough ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `$(document).ready` is called after the DOM is loaded, but this could happen before the images are actually loaded. You need `$(window).load` event which is triggered after the page is fully loaded including graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(window).load(function() {` you are good to go. Eg : http://jsfiddle.net/toopay/sQJq3/